# Change Wiki content into clear text

Tags: php, extract, wiki

I am doing a project in which I want to extract the text of wiki page. The output I get is:

> Processor - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia Processor From Wikipedia,
>   the free encyclopedia Jump to: navigation, search This disambiguation
>   page should be converted into a broad-concept article, describing the
>   primary meaning of the term. Additional meanings linked to this term
>   should be moved to a separate page with "(disambiguation)" in the
>   title. Look up processor in Wiktionary, the free dictionary.
>   Processor, Processor unit or Processing unit may refer to: Contents 1
>   Computing 2 Other 3 See also Computing [edit] Central processing unit
>   Processing unit, in Von Neumann computer architecture, contains an
>   arithmetic logic unit (ALU) and processor registers Microprocessor, a
>   CPU on one silicon chip as part of a microcomputer
>   Application-specific instruction-set processor, a component used in
>   system-on-a-chip design Graphics processing unit (GPU / VPU), a
>   dedicated graphics rendering device for a personal computer or game
>   console Physics processing unit (PPU), a dedicated microprocessor
>   designed to handle the calculations of physics Digital signal
>   processor, a specialized microprocessor designed specifically for
>   digital signal processing Network processor, a microprocessor
>   specifically targeted at the networking application domain Front end
>   processor, a helper processor for communication between a host
>   computer and other devices Coprocessor Floating-point unit Data
>   processing system, a system that translates or converts between
>   different data formats Word processor, a computer application used for
>   the production of printable material Audio processor, used in studios
>   and radio stations Other [edit] Food processor, an appliance used to
>   facilitate repetitive tasks in the preparation of food See also [edit]
>   Process (disambiguation) Data processing (disambiguation) This
>   disambiguation page lists articles associated with the same title. If
>   an internal link led you here, you may wish to change the link to
>   point directly to the intended article. Retrieved from
>   "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Processor&oldid=556083828"
>   Categories: Disambiguation pages to be converted to broad concept
>   articlesDisambiguation pagesHidden categories: All article
>   disambiguation pagesAll disambiguation pages Navigation menu Personal
>   tools Create accountLog in Namespaces Article Talk Variants Views Read
>   Edit View history Actions Search Navigation Main page Contents
>   Featured content Current events Random article Donate to Wikipedia
>   Interaction Help About Wikipedia Community portal Recent changes
>   Contact Wikipedia Toolbox What links here Related changes Upload file
>   Special pages Permanent link Page information Cite this page
>   Print/export Create a book Download as PDF Printable version Languages
>   Espa ol Nederlands Norsk bokm l Portugu s Sloven ina Edit links This
>   page was last modified on 21 May 2013 at 10:31. Text is available
>   under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License; additional
>   terms may apply. By using this site, you agree to the Terms of Use and
>   Privacy Policy. Wikipedia is a registered trademark of the Wikimedia
>   Foundation, Inc., a non-profit organization. Privacy policy About
>   Wikipedia Disclaimers Contact Wikipedia Mobile view Array

But I've expected the content as below...

> Pollution is the introduction of contaminants into the natural
>   environment that cause adverse change.Pollution can take the form of
>   chemical substances or energy, such as noise, heat or light.
>   Pollutants, the components of pollution, can be either foreign
>   substances/energies or naturally occurring contaminants. Pollution is
>   often classed as point source or nonpoint source pollution.

Is it possible to do from php or any other language, preserving the links?

Comment: Your question is vague and doesn't make sense in it's current form. Could you elaborate a bit ? For instance where and how do you get that text ? Why do you expect something else ? What have you tried to tackle this "problem" ?

Comment: I want to make  app that will crawl wiki page on the basis of tag given as input from a page . When user search the tag then the apps should provide him/her the description about the thing from artice that is on the wiki.. I dont want the whole page of wiki bt only the text that is only related to tag that the user has input to search and the related link as in wiki ??

Comment: It's probably possible, but you have to do some research. Also I though that wikipedia has an API, take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible with PHP and also with many other languages.

Comment: LOL............ You get my vote :p

Comment: Dear hakre, the can u plz provide me the sollution??